# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I think it's important to point out that this review is  different from the other types of reviews in the review queue. In this case, we're looking at the site from the *outside*, as if we were project managers looking for answers to a problem, and determining whether or not the answer to our problem would be here on *this* site or elsewhere on some *other* site. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to allow developers to get enough quality development time while keeping to support & maintenance obligations](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/how-to-allow-developers-to-get-enough-quality-development-time-while-keeping-to)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can 'relationship building' be a cop out?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9114/can-relationship-building-be-a-cop-out)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is an appropriate quality standard for requirements specifications?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9125/what-is-an-appropriate-quality-standard-for-requirements-specifications)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to handle confusion of "user stories" term in agile methodology?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/how-to-handle-confusion-of-user-stories-term-in-agile-methodology)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to start my first project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9212/how-to-start-my-first-project)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [PMP certification 35 contact hours- neccessary to be from training institute?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9106/pmp-certification-35-contact-hours-neccessary-to-be-from-training-institute)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to involve the whole team in choosing the next project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/how-to-involve-the-whole-team-in-choosing-the-next-project)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to define the yellow zone from the Critical Chain method for a new project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9167/how-to-define-the-yellow-zone-from-the-critical-chain-method-for-a-new-project)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Catch-Up Scheduling](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/catch-up-scheduling)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is there are a resource handler or gantt chart creator tool for JIRA?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/is-there-are-a-resource-handler-or-gantt-chart-creator-tool-for-jira)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)